# Vagrant up on Windows 10 virtualbox ignores administrative rights

Tags: vagrant, windows-10, virtualbox, administrator

I'm trying to set Vagrant's `sync_type` to `smb`, but fail on running `vagrant up` after changing the configuration.

I receive the following error:

> SMB shared folders require running Vagrant with administrative
>   privileges. This is a limitation of Windows, since creating new
>   network shares requires admin privileges. Please try again in a
>   console with proper permissions or use another synced folder type.

I launched both VirtualBox (the GUI) and Cygwin in administrator mode, but the error persisted. Using Git Bash, Powershell or CMD instead of Cygwin didn't fix it. Also re-installing VirtualBox as administrator did not change anything.

I'm running VirtualBox 5.0.24 r108355, Vagrant 1.8.4 and Windows 10 Pro, build 10586.420.

How can I get vagrant to recognize and use the administrator rights?

**UPDATE**
I found I am able to launch the machine from the VirtualBox GUI (started as admin), suggesting that the VirtualBox interface used by Cygwin may not be running in administrator mode. However, I'm currently unable to connect to the machine through Cygwin.

**UPDATE 2**
Running VirtualBox GUI as regular user also allowed me to boot the machine.

Answer (score 1):

To use the SMB synced folder type, the machine running Vagrant must be a Windows machine with PowerShell version 3 or later installed. In addition to this, the command prompt executing Vagrant must have administrative privileges. Vagrant requires these privileges in order to create new network folder shares.

https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/smb.html#prerequisites